# How to split string by numerics

Tags: tcl

I havetried to split but still failed.

```
set strdata "34a64323R6662w0332665323020346t534r66662v43037333444533053534a64323R6662w0332665323020346t534r66662v430373334445330535"

puts [split $strdata "3334445330535"] ;#<---- this command does not work

The result needed as below:
{34a64323R6662w0332665323020346t534r66662v43037} {34a64323R6662w0332665323020346t534r66662v43037}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `split` command's optional second argument is interpreted as a *set* of characters to split on, so it really isn't going to do what you want. However, there are other approaches. One of the simpler methods of doing what you want is to use `string map` to convert the character sequence into a character that isn't in the input data (Unicode is full of those!) and then `split` on that:

```
set strdata "34a64323R6662w0332665323020346t534r66662v43037333444533053534a64323R6662w0332665323020346t534r66662v430373334445330535"
set splitterm "3334445330535"

set items [split [string map [list $splitterm "\uFFFF"] $strdata] "\uFFFF"]
foreach i $items {
    puts "==> $i"
}
# ==> 34a64323R6662w0332665323020346t534r66662v43037
# ==> 34a64323R6662w0332665323020346t534r66662v43037
# ==> {}
```

Note that there is a `{}` (i.e., an empty-string list element) at the end because that's the string that came after the last split element. If you don't want that, add a `string trimright` between the `string map` and the `split`:

```
# Doing this in steps because the line is a bit long otherwise
set mapped  [string map [list $splitterm "\uFFFF"] $strdata]
set trimmed [string trimright $mapped "\uFFFF"]
set items   [split $trimmed "\uFFFF"]
```

Comment: Thanks Donald. What does mean "\uFFFF"?

Comment: It is an escaped version of a unicode character that won't occur in normal text *or* binary data; I think it isn't actually valid in serialized strings according to the Unicode Consortium. That is OK here, because we are just borrowing it temporarily as a marker for where to split; it means nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

The `split` command doesn't work like that, see the documentation.

Try making the data string into a list like this:

```
regsub -all 3334445330535 $strdata " "
```

i.e. replacing the delimiter with a space.

Documentation:
[regsub](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm)

Comment: Our use tcllib `textutil::splitx`, which basically does what you recommend.